# Передача переменных между playbook'ами Ansible для подстановки в шаблон

Tags: ansible

Никак не могу сообразить, можно ли в ansible использовать передачу переменных между playbook-ами без внешнего файла.

```
- hosts: local
    gather_facts: True
  tasks:
    - name: Get gateway
        set_fact: my_geteway="{{ ansible_defauld_ipv4.gateway }}"
```

До этого места всё идет нормально, переменная присваивается, передаётся в `.j2` файл если нужно и затем можно её потом использовать, но вопрос в следующем. Можно ли сделать так, продолжив playbook:

```
 - name: Echo my_gateway
        import_playbook: echo_ip.yml
          vars:
            gateway_echo: my_gateway
```

Сам файл `echo_ip.yml`

```
---
- hosts: outhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Echo
      debug: msg={{ gateway_echo }}
```

Comment: Вот не пользуюсь я пока фичами ansible 2.4... У меня без `import_playbook` всё работает на `include`'ах -- и проблем нет.

Comment: Да, собственно, можно и на старом ansible ответить. Мне кажется тут разницы нет. Вопрос в том - можно ли передать динамическую переменную без использования внешних файлов. В 2.4 include уже в DEPRICATED.

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт test_playbook_main.yml:

```
- name: main playbook, part 1
  hosts: adsfasdf
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
    - name: Get gateway
      set_fact: my_gateway="{{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}"
    - name: Dump var
      debug: msg="gate={{ my_gateway}}."

- include: echo_ip.yml aaa={{ my_gateway }}

- name: main playbook, part 3
  hosts: adsfasdf
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
    - name: Dump var
      debug: msg="gate={{ my_gateway}}."
```

Скрипт echo_ip.yml:

```
- name: echo_ip playbook
  hosts: adsfasdf
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Dump var
      debug: msg="gate={{ aaa }}."
```

Вывод:

```
PLAY [main playbook, part 1] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [adsfasdf]

TASK [Get gateway] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [adsfasdf]

TASK [Dump var] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [adsfasdf] => {
    "msg": "gate=1.2.3.1."
}

PLAY [echo_ip playbook] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Dump var] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [adsfasdf] => {
    "msg": "gate=1.2.3.1."
}

PLAY [main playbook, part 3] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [adsfasdf]

TASK [Dump var] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [adsfasdf] => {
    "msg": "gate=1.2.3.1."
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
adsfasdf : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

PS. Вариант для ansible 2.4 (через import_playbook) точно такой же, только замените `include` на `import_playbook`

Comment: Вынужден поправить свой комментарий. Данное решение действительно лишь в рамках одного хоста. При использовании данных на другом хосте(ах) это не работает.